# Write a framework like jQuery

Tags: javascript

I know a lot of questions like this exist. I've checked them all, and they are all trying to do something different to what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically, things like each() is a long thing to write in pure javascript `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".class"), function() {})` rather than `$(".class").each(function() {})`

However things like .css() I'll never need because `element.style.display = "block"` is easy.

I would like to be able to do things like `$(".class").style.display = "block"` but also `$(".class").each()`

I was trying:

```
function init(s, p) {
    var n = (p||document).querySelectorAll(s);
    var e = function(n, f) { [].forEach.call(n, f); }

    this.each = function(f) { e(n, f) }

    return n.length == 1 ? n[0] : n;
}

function $(s, p) { return new init(s, p) }

$(".parent").classList.add("hello");
$(".child").each(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

I could get them working individually but not together. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Writing your own jQuery](http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery) - it's a really well written article about how this sort of thing can work.

Comment: @Red jQuery lite? I would say for two reasons,
1. I know jQuery, but I know jQuery better than Javascript and that's a problem.
2. I don't want to have everything jQuery provides on most projects. I only ever use 5% of jQuery I would say.

Comment: I would suggest to look at [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) library. It has many utility methods incl. ones dealing with array-like collections, e.g. [`_.each`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) for your case. However it doesn't directly deal with DOM and cannot create collections of DOM elements. So you still need use `document.querySelectorAll` or similar methods.

Comment: Why not copying the `jQuery` functions you want to use, and place them inside an own script. That way you can make it the way you want, and keep it simple.